# Calculating body volume? (3-variables)

Tags: calculus

How do we calculate a body's volume in 3 coordinates?
For example:

> Find the volume of the following body: $T = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^3 | 0 \leq x, x^2 \leq y \leq \sqrt{x}, 0 \leq z \leq xy \}$.

How exactly do we find the function in the notation of $z$? What is the equation we are looking for?

Thank you.

Comment: I assume you know how to integrate in several variables. you just need to find the characteristic function of your region and integrate it with respect to Lebesgue measure using any tools you find handy, (mostly change of variables to find a suitable parametrization and Fubini's thm, what you do exactly depends on a particular region of course)

Comment: $\iiint\limits_D dx dy dz$. I think the surface $z=xy$ is called hyperbolic paraboloid.

Answer (score 1):

This is a triple integral problem, where you integrate 1. The inequalities give you all the bounds in the correct order, except that there is no upper bound for $x$. Try sketching the region given by the $x$ and $y$ inequalities, and that will give you the upper bound of $x$.

Comment: Interesting to see this in a previous exam when we haven't learned triple integrals

Comment: It's also a double integral of $z=xy$, since it's the area under that $z$ function.

Comment: Can you please show me how to do that?